# Can't set up port forwarding on ZyXEL DSL router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, router, port-forwarding

I'm trying to set up SSH connection with a PC that is behind the DSL router.

I do know that to do that - I need to turn off the firewall on the router and set up port forwarding.

So my firewall is off.

Forwarding is set up (according to this manual: http://qwest.centurylink.com/internethelp/modem-pk5000z-adv-port-forwarding.html

SSH to localhost works.

SSH through global IP doesn't work (just keeps connecting until I turn it off).

Is there anything else I need to do on ZyXel?

I was setting up the same thing on TP-Link router - and it took me two minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. I solved mine with nat rule from 2222 beginning port to 22 end port. Then I can succesfully connect to server with `ssh user@global.ip -p 2222` command.